# Can analyze win7 BSOD crash screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, crash

Lenovo Laptop with windows 7 x64. Cane analize the BSOD of crash dump for me? Is related to power interrupt issue?

I have attached the file as well.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2kd41j48ui0kus/080217-24445-01.dmp?dl=0

```
Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1000009F, {4, 258, fffffa80066d6b50, fffff800048c43d0}

Implicit thread is now fffffa80`066d6b50
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for win32k.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for win32k.sys
Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!KiSwapContext+7a )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000004, The power transition timed out waiting to synchronize with the Pnp
    subsystem.
Arg2: 0000000000000258, Timeout in seconds.
Arg3: fffffa80066d6b50, The thread currently holding on to the Pnp lock.
Arg4: fffff800048c43d0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_PNP on Win7 and higher
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the call stack, from the dump file:

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
fffff880`0370f620 fffff800`030c9de2 nt!KiSwapContext+0x7a
fffff880`0370f760 fffff800`030db1cf nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x1d2
fffff880`0370f7f0 fffff800`030b3ebe nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
fffff880`0370f890 fffff800`030d95ec nt!ExpWaitForResource+0xae
fffff880`0370f900 fffff800`034140a0 nt!ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite+0x14f
fffff880`0370f970 fffff800`03558ce7 nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x1702c
fffff880`0370f9a0 fffff800`03559efc nt!PnpProcessQueryRemoveAndEject+0x77
fffff880`0370fae0 fffff800`034430a6 nt!PnpProcessTargetDeviceEvent+0x4c
fffff880`0370fb10 fffff800`030dd355 nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x4e93b
fffff880`0370fb70 fffff800`0336d43a nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x111
fffff880`0370fc00 fffff800`030c50c6 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`0370fc40 00000000`00000000 nt!KxStartSystemThread+0x16
```

as we can see, it seems that windows was waiting for a device to "eject" (=safe for removal)  (QueryRemoveAndEject)

and then a timeout occured...

You probably have a faulty plug and play device on your computer, try to disconnect everything (especially the USB drives!)